# unknow error when use SOQL query to get data in workbench

Tags: soql, error

we have the below error message since last weekn whenever use SOQL query to query data:

"UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379"